# inbook type dashes out the author name when author and editor are the same

Tags: biblatex

My problem is that when the author and the editor names are the same in @inbook, author name is not shown in bibliography. Instead there is a dash. I'm already using dashed=false option. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, date=year, firstinits=true, natbib=true]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[turkish]{babel}
    \usepackage{filecontents}



\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @inbook{diamond1984,
author = "Diamond, J.",
title = "Normal extinction of isolated populations.",
booktitle = "In Extinctions",
publisher = "University of Chicago Press",
year = "1984",
editor = "Nitecki, M. H.",
pages="191-246",
location="Chicago",
pagetotal = "354"
}

@inbook{spellerberg1996,
  author = "Spellerberg, I. F.",
  title = "Themes, terms and concepts.",
  booktitle = "Conservation Biology",
  publisher = "Longman",
  year = "1996",
  editor = "Spellerberg, I. F.",
  pages="18-35",
  location="London",
  pagetotal = "242"
}

\end{filecontents*}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\section{mwe}
{
Test \citep{diamond1984, spellerberg1996}
}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

biblatex.cfg:

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}

% Put your definitions here.

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,book,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {citetitle}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,book,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}


\DeclareFieldFormat
  [inbook,incollection]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\ifentrytype{inbook}{\mkbibparens{#1}}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\AtBeginBibliography{
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  pages = {s},
  references = {Kaynakça},
  urlseen = {Erişim Tarihi},
  and = {ve},
  andothers = {vd\adddot}
}

\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {%\printtext[parens]{%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
         {\printdateextralabel}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}%}%

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{pagetotal}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\ifnamesequal{author}{editor}
      {\bibnamedash}
      {\printnames{editor}}%
     \addspace
     \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {}
       {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{booktitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[booktitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}%
       \setunit{\space}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{booksubtitle}}%
    }%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printfield{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \printurldate}}

\endinput
```

Comment: Usually you have to choose between the author or the editor, not both. What is the style are you using for? Could you add a MWE?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). How things are formatted depends very heavily on the options you provide to `biblatex` and, possibly, on your class as well. A guessing game is in nobody's interests but that would be the best we could do without more information ;). It is, however, odd to include an editor in an `@inbook` entry.

Comment: There are books with different authors for different sections. I don't think a MWE is necessary just try the samples I've just added. One of them works normal, but the one with the same author and editor name raises the dashing problem.

Comment: In order to 'just try the samples', I would have to construct an MWE. So clearly an MWE **is** necessary since you are asking people to reproduce the issue. What you are saying is that you don't want to bother providing one so you expect anybody who wants to help you to create one independently. And, as Peter Gill keeps saying, problems may be fun to solve but they are not fun to set up.

Comment: Anyway, the first example should be `@incollection` - ***not*** `@inbook` - and the second ought not have an `editor` at all.

Comment: @cfr For The seconde camole I do net see and reason why the editor of a collection cannot be the author of one of the contributions (so it can be an `incollection` entry type.

Comment: @Guido. Indeed, in that case, it should be `@incollection`. I didn't mean to rule that out. But if it is, indeed, an `@inbook` entry, it ought not have an `editor`.

Comment: @cfr Ok ok it's my bad sorry. I tought the problem was a simple one that you can figure out easily but I was wrong. I added the mwe to the question. Thanks.

Comment: The definition of `byeditor+others` is the problem. There you tell `biblatex` to use a dash if the author and editor are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are setting `dashed=false` anyway, you can just remove the definition of the macro `byeditor+others` which tells `biblatex` to use a dash when the author and editor are the same:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, date=year, firstinits=true, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  % this should probably be @incollection if the book is an anthology of some kind. You really ought not include full stops in the titles except if they occur in the middle of the title
  @inbook{diamond1984,
    author = "Diamond, J.",
    title = "Normal extinction of isolated populations",
    booktitle = "In Extinctions",
    publisher = "University of Chicago Press",
    year = "1984",
    editor = "Nitecki, M. H.",
    pages="191-246",
    location="Chicago",
    pagetotal = "354"
  }

  @inbook{spellerberg1996,
    author = "Spellerberg, I. F.",
    title = "Themes, terms and concepts",
    booktitle = "Conservation Biology",
    publisher = "Longman",
    year = "1996",
    editor = "Spellerberg, I. F.",
    pages="18-35",
    location="London",
    pagetotal = "242"
  }
\end{filecontents*}
% \ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}

% Put your definitions here.

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,book,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {citetitle}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,book,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [inbook,incollection]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\ifentrytype{inbook}{\mkbibparens{#1}}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

\AtBeginBibliography{
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  pages = {s},
  references = {Kaynakça},
  urlseen = {Erişim Tarihi},
  and = {ve},
  andothers = {vd\adddot}
}

\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {%\printtext[parens]{%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
         {\printdateextralabel}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}%}%

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{pagetotal}
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}
  \newunit}

% \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
%   \ifnameundef{editor}
%     {}
%     {\ifnamesequal{author}{editor}
%       {\bibnamedash}
%       {\printnames{editor}}%
%      \addspace
%      \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
%      \clearname{editor}}
%     {}}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {}
       {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}%
        \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{booktitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[booktitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}%
       \setunit{\space}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{booksubtitle}}%
    }%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printfield{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \printurldate}}

% \endinput

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

  \section{mwe}
  {
    Test \citep{diamond1984, spellerberg1996}
  }

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Dashless]

Note that `@inbook` is ***not*** intended for things like anthologies with multiple authors of different articles. You should use `@incollection` in that case.

Comment: Thanks, removing that part completely raised other problems for me, but just removing the if clause that checks whether the names are the same solved the problem. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @krypt That makes sense. I didn't fully follow what was meant to do what but it did seem that telling it to use dashes might be counter-productive! (If you are like me, you stick things in `.cfg` files and then forget about them and are therefore extremely confused by weird output.)

Comment: Haha yeah I am exactly like you. I have probably broken something else by fixing this. But, it is another day's problem. Thanks again.